# How to save NSArray or NSDictionary to JSON file ?

Tags: xml, ios, json, serialization

[JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) provides awesome way to decode JSON file, what is the best way to do the opposite way to encode objects to JSON file ?
BTW: Here is [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) for loading & saving with XML.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

iOS 5 now has everything needed to do that :

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filepath append:yesOrNo];
[outputStream open];

[NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:nsDicOrNSArrayObject 
                            toStream:outputStream 
                             options:0 
                               error:&error];
[outputStream close];
```

Answer (score 4):

JSONKit also has everything you need to retrieve a JSON value from NSArrays and NSDictionarys.

```
NSString *jsonString = [yourDictionary JSONString];
```

Comment: can not work for my case. I just have NSArray, which has hundreds of simple items, each item is just two float attributes.

Comment: Why, exactly, won't it work?  JSONKit has json categories for NSArray too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)? I've used it for both parsing and generation of JSON in several projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *json1= [ NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject :info options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

if you want to convert dictionary into json data then use dataWithJSONObject